# Android Sms Receiver Result to Main Activity

Tags: android

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.anaekran);
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String smsMsj = getIntent().getStringExtra("sms");
                if(smsMsj != null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), smsMsj, 2).show();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        t.start();
    }
}
```

SmsReceiver.java

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle mesaj = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] smsMessage = null;
        String msj = "";

        if(mesaj!= null){
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])mesaj.get("pdus");
            smsMessage = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++){
                smsMessage[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                msj = smsMessage[i].getMessageBody();
            }

            Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, SmsReceiver.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("sms", msj);
        }
    }
}
```

My receiver working correctly but i have one problem when message coming i want to show on my MainAcitivty toast, so i create mIntent in receiver class, and then im use putExtra method.

But not working, sory for my bad english and thank you :)

Comment: you cannot show a toast from a non-UI thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using explicit `Intent` and starting it could help you, hm? :)

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("sms", msj);
context.startActivity(mIntent);
```

Your mistake is that you construct your new `Intent` with `SmsReceiver.class` (but you need to launch `MainActivity`) and that you do not start any activity with such an intent.

**Edit 1:** Also, pay attention - you are trying to run a toast inside your worker thread. This is not possible. Remove your anonymous Thread and move your toast code to your `onCreate(Bundle)`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveState){  
    ....
    String smsMsj = getIntent().getStringExtra("sms");
    if(smsMsj != null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), smsMsj, 2).show();
    }
    ....
}
```

**Edit 2**: Moreover, your **duration** parameter in `Toast.makeText(..)` is set to **2**. This does not correspond to any magic constant in `Toast` class. You have to use one of the constants: **Toast.LENGTH_LONG** or **Toast.LENGTH_SHORT**. So, rewrite your code to:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplication(), smsMsj, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Comment: he still wont see the toast because he is trying to show the toast in a non-ui thread though

Comment: Yeah, You are absolutely correct. I did not notice he's starting a toast in his worker thread. I corrected my answer